# Is there a TSDoc tag other than @returns for type guards functions?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, tsdoc

I was adding TSDoc to a type guard function and found out that using `@returns` might not be the most appropriate way to document a type guard.

```
/**
 * Type guard to tell if a pet is a fish or a bird.
 * 
 * @param pet - A pet that is either a fish or a bird.
 * 
 * @returns True if the pet can swim, otherwise false.
 */
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Are there other ways like `@casts` that might be more meaningful than documenting what the boolean value does on the function?

```
/**
 * Type guard to tell if a pet is a fish or a bird.
 * 
 * @param pet - A pet that is either a fish or a bird.
 * 
 * @casts The pet is a `Fish` if it can `swim`, otherwise it is a `Bird`.
 */
function isFish2(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe sure doc comments have this feature. But `@returns True` is 100% accurate.